# Navbar retracts on scroll down and appears on scroll up according to scroll value

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, jquery-waypoints, scrollmagic

I have a navigation bar which is 110px high, and absolutely positioned. Up to 80     pixels its set to `position:absolute;` , and after 80px it becomes `position:fixed;` with a `transform: translate(-80px, 0);`. So technically  is partly pinned (the 30 remaining pixels of the bottom) after an amount of scroll of 80px. ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/exjf7yk3/1/))

I'd like to see the navigation bar again on scroll up at any point of the page, and not just when it's at the top of the page. And that when you scroll down again it dissapear in the same fashion. I know how to do that with `jquery waypoints` via `if (direction === 'down')` which could trigger a `transform: translate(-80px, 0);` to make it fit back in place if scroll is up and then dissappear again if scroll is down (with a css3 transition).

What I'd really like to do though is to have it link with the actual number of pixels scrolled. So if I scroll down (let's say half the page) and then I scroll up 10 pixels, the navigation bar is taking 10 extra pixels. If I scroll again 20 pixels up, then 20 pixels more on the navigation bar. This until the whole bar appears. Then a scroll up would not do anything since the bar appeared. And if I scroll down 5 pixels, 5 pixels less, etc.

What I'd like to do is featured on this website's header: [EXAMPLE (www.oma.eu)](http://www.oma.eu)

I've been looking through Scrollmagic (the plugin) since basically I could set up a Scene (with `transform: translate(-80px, 0);` and give a duration of 80 pixels. The only concern is that I need a TriggerElement, but the scene needs to be apply on any time there's a scroll, not in a specific moment.

Any insights on how I could logically do this? OMA's website's function is pretty obscure to me...

This is what their javascript seems to do:

a) detects when there's a change of scroll direction.

b) after detecting the change, get the value (x) scrolled live, up to to 80px.

c) injects inside `transform: translate` from the navigation bar this value, up to 80px.

d) if scrolled less than 80px and changed scroll direction, take the new last value (y) and substract (x) from it.

Is it possible, is there an easy way to achieve this effect?

Comment: You can use this to attach a funcion on scroll event: $(window).on('scroll', scrollBody); Then in scrollBody function, inspect the scroll from the top and add/remove classes or styles:  function scrollBodyConta() {  if ($(document).scrollTop() < 80) { .... } }

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hd0jx957/

It does the same as I did with my jsfiddle

Comment: Would it make sense to use `scrollBy` instead of `scrollTop`?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollBy

Comment: this jsfiddle does exactly what I've commented

Comment: ScrollTop is an absolute value, from what I understand. What i need is a "relative" is the scroll value of a scroll event (and not scroll position from the top). If you're at the bottom of the page and scroll up, then the navbar reappears, independently if it's at the "page up" or in the middle of the page.

Comment: This might help you out: http://scrollmagic.io/examples/basic/custom_actions.html I haven't tried it myself but it looks like `e.target.controller().info("scrollDirection")` will get you started. For getting the x value of the scroll you might have to do that yourself (subtract the last value from the current one) or you might be able to set a tween to do that.